# Actualização BD Website

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, asp.net

Estou precisar de ajuda pois estou a fazer um site onde :
mostro os valores das linhas da BD e tenho a opção de fazer a atualização dos dados via Web.

Quando tento fazer a atualização da-me o seguinte erro:

> Descrição: Exceção não processada ao executar o pedido Web atual. Consulte o rastreio da pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e o respetivo ponto de origem no código.
>
> Detalhes da Exceção: System.ArgumentException: Não é possível definir um valor null para a Column 'Salario'. Em vez disso, utilize DBNull.

O excerto de código é este :

```
 protected void Grid2_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow r1 = Grid2.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    rtrab = tabtrab.FindById((int)Grid2.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
    if (rtrab != null)
    {
        rtrab["Salario"] = ((TextBox)r1.FindControl("TxtSalario"));
    }
    Grid2.EditIndex = -1;
    adpt1 = new tb_trabalhadorTableAdapter();
    adpt1.Update(tabtrab);
    adpt1.Filltrabalhador(tabtrab);
    enchegrid();
}
```

A linha do erro é este :

```
   {
        rtrab["Salario"] = ((TextBox)r1.FindControl("TxtSalario"));
    }
```

Comment: ((TextBox)r1.FindControl("TxtSalario")) esta retornado null, tente verificar o valor antes de seta no campo

Comment: ((TextBox)r1.FindControl("TxtSalario")).Text; quando uso texto coloco .Text e se for apenas valores inteiros coloco alguma coisa para substituir o text ?

Comment: Não, @ChrisAdler. Você vai ter que converter o valor pra número.